# BASH: Regex -> empty result

Tags: regex, string, bash

I'm using bash but I do not get a bash rematch... Every online regex check tool worked fine for this string and regex.

```
#!/bin/bash 
set -x
regex='hd_profile_pic_url_info": {"url": "([0-9a-zA-Z._:\/\-_]*)"'
str='{"user": {"pk": 12345, "username": "dummy", "full_name": "dummy", "is_private": true, "profile_pic_url": "censored", "profile_pic_id": "censored", "is_verified": false, "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false, "media_count": 0, "follower_count": 71114, "following_count": 11111, "biography": "", "external_url": "", "usertags_count": 0, "hd_profile_pic_versions": [{"width": 320, "height": 320, "url": "censored"}, {"width": 640, "height": 640, "url": "censored"}], "hd_profile_pic_url_info": {"url": "https://scontent-frt3-2.cdninstagram.com/vp/censored/censored_a.jpg", "width": 930, "height": 930}, "has_highlight_reels": false, "auto_expand_chaining": false}, "status": "ok"}'
[[ $str =~ $regex ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH}
```

Comment: It would be a lot simpler to use `jq` to get the value you want instead. `echo "$str" | jq -r '.user.hd_profile_pic_url_info.url'`

Comment: [Just escape `{`.](https://ideone.com/AG4ygr) And move `-` to the end of the bracket expression.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing json with bash it's not a good idea, as others said, `jq` is the right tool for the job.

Having said that, I think

```
regex='hd_profile_pic_url_info": {"url": "[0-9a-zA-Z._:\/_-]*"'
```

would work. Notice the '-' as the last char in the set, to avoid being interpreted as a range.

Comment: I never used jq so it wasn't in my mind. But now my script works, ty :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the duplicate `_` at the end of your regex :

```
regex='"hd_profile_pic_url_info": {"url": "([0-9a-zA-Z._:\/\-]*)"'
```